# Prove exhaustivity of print function based on a string map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, proof, proof-of-correctness, curry-howard

When I have an "enum" type, that is, an algebraic data type where none of the cases wrap any other data, I commonly like to project a parser/printer off of a mapping to string, to make sure the parser and printer stay in sync as I change code. For example, in Idris:

```
data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors

Eq RPS where
  Rock == Rock = True
  Paper == Paper = True
  Scissors == Scissors = True
  _ == _ = False

StrMap : List (RPS, String)
StrMap =
  [ (Rock, "rock")
  , (Paper, "paper")
  , (Scissors, "scissors")
  ]
```

I might implement a print function as follows:

```
print' : RPS -> Maybe String
print' rps = lookup rps StrMap
```

The problem is, I don't want a `Maybe` here. I would like to guarantee at compile-time that I have covered all my cases, just like I could if I had written this function by case-splitting on `RPS`, where the exhaustivity checker would kick in and I could just have `print : RPS -> string`. In Idris, I know how to recover this with a proof (don't you just love Idris!):

```
print_exhaustive : (rps : RPS) -> IsJust (print' rps)
print_exhaustive Rock = ItIsJust
print_exhaustive Paper = ItIsJust
print_exhaustive Scissors = ItIsJust

justGetIt : (m : Maybe a) -> IsJust m -> a
justGetIt (Just y) ItIsJust = y

print : RPS -> String
print rps with (isItJust (print' rps))
  | Yes itIs = justGetIt (print' rps) itIs
  | No itsNot = absurd $ itsNot $ print_exhaustive rps
```

Now in my opinion this is fantastic. I am able to declare in exactly one place in my code what the correlation between an enum case and its associated string is, and I can have a `print` function and a `parse` function both written with it (the `parse` function is omitted here as not relevant to the question, but is trivial to implement). Not only that, but I have been able to convince the typechecker that my `print : RPS -> String` signature that I wanted isn't bogus, and have avoided the use of any partial functions! This is how I like to work.

However at work most of my code is in F#, not in Idris, so what I end up doing instead is using FsCheck to quasi-prove exhaustivity with a property-based test. That's not too bad, but

1. The property-based test isn't collocated with the `StrMap`; it is in a different assembly. I like to collocate my invariants with what they refer to as much as possible.
2. You could get further in the build process before encountering a failure if you e.g. added a case and forgot to change the `StrMap`; if you were just sitting there recompiling, as I often do, you would miss it until you actually ran the tests.
3. I have to use non-exhaustive functions to implement it, because of the weaker type system. This muddies the clarity of what I'm trying to teach my coworkers; I've been trying to convince them of the glory of total functional programming.

We've just started a new project in Haskell, and I've hit a scenario like this. Of course I can use QuickCheck and `fromJust` and implement the F# strategy, and that should be fine.

But what I'm wondering is: since Haskell community and ecosystem emphasizes the Curry-Howard correspondence in a way that F#'s community and ecosystem doesn't, and since all kinds of fancy extensions have been added in recent days to enable the use of dependent types, shouldn't I be able to follow my Idris strategy for this instead? Someone told me that I should be able to translate anything I can write in Idris to Haskell without loosing type safety if I turned on enough extensions (and was willing to introduce enough verbosity etc). I don't know whether this is true or not, but if it is true, I would like to know what extensions to turn on, and what kind of code to write, in order to follow my Idris strategy for this in Haskell. Also worthy of note: I could believe that my Idris strategy is not the most simple/elegant way of doing it in that language.

How can I translate this Idris code to Haskell in order to implement `print :: RPS -> String` without invoking any partial functions?

Comment: For a low-tech solution, are you willing to trust the derived `Enum` and `Bounded` instances for enum types? Because if yes, you can write `print` as a straight function, and for `parse`, use a map you can build via `[ (a, print a) | a <- [minBound..maxBound] ]`

Comment: @cactus Hm, hadn't thought about that. I've heard of those typeclasses before, but haven't ever used them (I've written mostly F# and Idris, not so much Haskell, and Idris doesn't have `deriving` yet, etc...) and so they aren't much on my radar. Care to flesh that out into a full answer?

Comment: I think you can generate Show and Read instances (or just print and parse functions) with some TH. Not an ideal solution but it may also work with things other than enums.

Comment: @n.m. I have read the paper about invertible syntax descriptions actually was able to implement enough of it in F# to generate a parser/printer between CLI arguments and an algebraic data type. They did use Template Haskell. I don't know much about Template Haskell though. My F# version had more boilerplate than theirs.

Comment: @n.m. however that did require more than template Haskell: they needed accompanying type classes, algebra of syntaxes, etc. Enumerations are the degenerate case where it is much easier though.

Comment: I still don't understand what is special of `StrMap` function? Is the string in map are constant? It seems cannot be modified.  If it is a constant, it is no different of using pattern matching map argument of function to `String` in Haskell.

Answer (score 4):

*If* you are willing to trust the derived `Enum` and `Bounded` instances for your enum type, then that gives you a way to enumerate your "`RPS` universe" using `[minBound..maxBound]`. That means you can *start* from a total function `print :: RPS -> String`, and tabulate that to compute `parse` from it:

```
print :: RPS -> String

parse :: String -> Maybe RPS
parse = \s -> lookup s tab
  where 
    tab = [(print x, x) | x <- [minBound..maxBound]]
```

Comment: Different way of attacking it, but for what I can tell accomplishes same goal. Will have to try it out. Thanks!

Comment: finally got a chance to try this out, and it's looking like it's gonna work great. I'm not going to accept the answer, because even though it solves my problem, I am still interested in the question of theorem-proving in Haskell, which is more directly posed. However I did +1 and I appreciate the idiomatic Haskell approach (make this particular example of theorem-proving much less interesting).